# Only menu shows on MODX Manager screen after fresh installation

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

After fresh installation CMF MODX Revo 2.2.2 into server, I got blank screen only with menu, and empty content
I change compress_css and copress_js values to 0, but no changes

What can be matter with it?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache [delete the files on disk, don't just click the clear cache menu item] if still no-go check both your modx error log & the server error logs, if nothing still turn up your debugging to 3 or 4 & check again.

Comment: I had many error in setup log like "(ERROR @ /setup/index.php) Could not install files from /home/zt/public_html/core/packages/core/xPDOFileVehicle/b02a4b17cb43ab756fc21d5823d1cb25/ to /home/zt/public_html/connectors/" Then I set correct permissions to files and folders and run setup one more, no log with errors any more

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Also, have a look in Chrome Dev Tools and see which error messages are appearing in the console.